# How do you start Python Paramiko SFTP with sudo?

Tags: python, sftp, sudo, paramiko, su

Using the standard `client.open_sftp()` handle gives me SFTP controls but without sudo/root permissions, any sort of `/etc/**` files can't be edited. I have a user that has passwordless sudo access, I figured I could maybe start off with `sudo su` and then invoke SFTP but that did not seem to be the case.

```
t = paramiko.Transport(('192.168.56.102', 22))  
t.connect(username='vagrant', password='vagrant')
chan = t.open_session()
chan.get_pty()
chan.invoke_subsystem('sftp')
chan.exec_command('sudo su')
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
```

.. the error

> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Channel closed.
>   DEBUG:paramiko.transport:EOF in transport thread

Any tips how to get Paramiko to open SFTP with sudo access?

Answer (score 0):

First, automating `su` or `sudo` is not the correct solution.

The correct solution is to setup a dedicated private key with only privileges needed for your task.

---

The `invoke_subsystem` and `exec_command` are generally mutually exclusive. You can use one or the other, but not both. A "subsystem" is kind of an alias to a "command". I.e. the `"sftp"` subsystem is typically an alias to the `"/bin/sftp-server"` command (thought that's a very simplified explanation).

---

There's no native support for executing SFTP subsystem as a different user.

So all you can do is to execute the `sftp_server` binary directly as a different user.

```
chan.exec_command('sudo su -c /bin/sftp-server')
```

(Assuming *nix OpenSSH server)

And you definitely cannot request PTY (`get_pty`) as that's incompatible with the SFTP protocol.

Comment: I tried this out but it didn't work. If your OpenSSH sshd_config has "Subsystem sftp <path to sftp_server>", then running this operation does not have any effect on the underlying user.

Comment: My answer has nothing to do with `Subsystem` directive. It actually bypasses it. So I do not understand your comment.

Comment: I tried out your proposed solution, but kept getting permission denied errors. When I do grep -e "sftp" on my machine, I see that sftp_server is not running. From what I understand, OpenSSH starts the sftp_server process when a sftp connection is being made. In this situation, the solution you have proposed here does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "my machine"? Server of client? What *"permission denied errors"*? What do you mean by *"this situation"*? I think you should start a new question as this will hardly get resolved with little information you can provide in comments.

Comment: My question is very similar to this question but I added additional content: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50035927/running-an-operation-as-a-different-user-via-python-paramiko-sftp