# Running an SFTP operation as a different user via Python Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko, su

I want connect to my Ubuntu server using a service account but perform file transfer operations on behalf of another user. My `sshd_config` has the following content (among other stuff):

```
PubKeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication yes
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

I have tried the following code but without any success:

```
t = paramiko.Transport(('<address>', <port>))  
t.connect(username='serviceAccount', password='<password>')
channel = t.open_session()
channel.exec_command('sudo su -l <other user> -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server')
sftp = t.open_sftp_client()
file = sftp.file("<some path>", "w", bufsize=...)
file.write(...)
file.close()
sftp.close()
channel.close()
t.close()
```

This is the error I see when I run this code:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

First, automating `su` or `sudo` is not the correct solution.

The correct solution is to login directly with the account you need to use.

---

Anyway, `open_sftp_client` and `exec_command` run on two different SSH channels. So your code cannot work, as the `sftp` operates on non-elevated session, that's not affected by the `exec_command` at all.

There's no explicit support for running SFTP with `su` in Paramiko (as that approach is wrong and hardly standardized).

You would have to implement an alternative to [`SFTPClient.from_transport`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.from_transport) that will call your `exec_command` instead of `invoke_subsystem`.